# Load Image Based Off URL ID

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image

I am trying to load an image based off the ID in the URL:

For example: www.exampleurl.com/API/upload/1.jpg holds an image.

I am trying to load that image into a separate PHP file when I go to: www.exampleurl.com/photo/index.php?id=1

The code I have so far doesn't seem to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    intval($_GET['id']);
?>
    <h1> <center> This is the image: </center> </h1>
    <img src="http://exampleurl.com/API/upload/<?php echo $id;?>.jpg" alt="some_text">
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wrap it in a `a` tag and give it the correct URL

Comment: not sure if this is the problem but note the "s" in uploads in the img URL

Comment: @asg In the question you have "uploads" in the URL, but in your code you have "upload"

Comment: @thatidiotguy That's not the issue. Just a question error.

Comment: you forgot to define `$id`

Answer (score 4):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    ?>
        <h1> <center> This is the image: </center> </h1>
        <img src="http://exampleurl.com/API/upload/<?php echo $id;?>.jpg" alt="some_text">
    </body>
    </html>
```

You have to specify $id

Comment: yw, happens to everyone! Myself included :)